# Bindear un dato dentro de un image.onload en Vue JS

Tags: imagen, vue.js, binding

Recibo una URL de una imagen desde una BBDD. Lo que busco es obtener el ancho y el alto de la imagen para formar un carrusel. Para ello instancio un objeto imagen dentro de un bucle for, pero las dimensiones no las obtengo porque todavía no se carga. Para solucionarlo utilizo onload, pero no logro bindear el dato dentro de la funcion onload para recibirlo en $data en el componente de Vue js.

La estructura de dataphoto es correcta, si lo prueba fuera de onload funciona correctamente.

```
dataphoto": [
{
  "id_foto": "107",
  "nombre": "Chrysanthemum.jpg",
  "ruta": "picsloaded/93/Chrysanthemum.jpg",
  "toma": "93",
  "width": 0,
  "height": 0
}

....
]




 getPictureData: function() {
  var self = this;
  var foto = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < this.dataphoto.length; i++) {

    foto = new Image();
    foto.src = "/static/api/" + this.dataphoto[i].ruta;

   foto.onload = (function(nr){

          self.dataphoto[nr]["width"] = foto.width;
          self.dataphoto[nr]["height"] = foto.height;


   })(i);
  }
```

},

Comment: No has asignado nada a foto.onload con ese código, puesto que la función no devuelve nada

Answer (score 1):

He logrado solucionar utilizando este código...

```
getPictureData: function() {
  var self = this;
  var foto = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < this.dataphoto.length; i++) {


    foto = new Image();
    foto.src = "/static/api/" + this.dataphoto[i].ruta;

   foto.onload = (function(nr){

    var photoWidth = foto.width;
    var photoHeight = foto.height;
      return function (){

        console.log(nr, foto.width, photoWidth, photoHeight)
        console.log(self.dataphoto)
          self.dataphoto[nr]["width"] = photoWidth ;
          self.dataphoto[nr]["height"] = photoHeight;
      }

   })(i);

   var loadedPhoto = foto.onload;
   loadedPhoto();
  }
```

},

Comment: La carga de imágenes es asíncrona, dado que utilizas la misma variable `foto`, el código que presentas tendrá errores o resultados inesperados.

Answer (score 1):

Tan simple como:

```
const newphotos = [];
this.dataphoto.forEach((photo) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = () => {
    const { width, height } = img;
    newphotos.push({ ...photo, width, height });
  };
  img.src = photo.url;
});
this.dataphoto = newphotos;
```

El nuevo array `newphotos` es por si quieres que el DOM se actualice luego de obtener las dimensiones.

Comment: Ese es básicamente el código que tratas de hacer, pero es probable tengas problemas por concepto de asincronía, en ese caso es mejor hacerlo de forma recursiva.

Comment: Qué tal Guz, concuerdo con tu respuesta, solo tengo un comentario/duda. ¿Hay alguna razón por la cual utilizas el estilo DOM0 para asignar el evento `load`? ¿Por qué no usar `addEventListener`? Entiendo que solo se asignará un evento, pero igual la última opción presentada es más flexible. En este caso al utilizar ES6 no estamos preocupándonos por compatibilidad.

Comment: @Ricky Buena pregunta. Cuando usas `addEventListener` **añades los listeners a una cola**, esto te permite añadir múltiples listeners que se ejecutarán secuencialmente. En este caso no nos interesa esa funcionalidad, así que optamos por el `onload` (sobreescribe cualquier listener previo). Aún así, como `img` es una variable local no hay diferencias entre usar `onload` o `addEventListener`. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias @Guz, si entiendo el funcionamiento de `addEventListener` quería saber tu opinión sobre seguir utilizando `DOM0` ya que muchos desarrolladores no lo recomiendan. Gracias nuevamente. Saludos.

Comment: @Ricky oh disculpa, entendí mal en el móvil =). Respondiendo a tu pregunta, no es recomendado cuando trabajas con **elementos controlados**, en este caso no tiene sentido que se use el DOM ya que esto lo hace Vue "virtualmente" para luego ser reflejado en el real. Pero como se trata de un elemento no controlado, esto es perfectamente factible.

Answer (score -1):

El problema viene de este código:

```
foto.onload = (function(nr) {
  self.dataphoto[nr]["width"] = foto.width;
  self.dataphoto[nr]["height"] = foto.height;
})(i);
```

que es equivalente a lo siguiente:

```
let func=function (nr) {
  self.dataphoto[nr]["width"] = foto.width;
  self.dataphoto[nr]["height"] = foto.height;
}
let callback=func(i);
foto.onload=callback;
```

Como ves, defines a una función, a la que llamas con el parámetro `i` y el resultado (que es `undefined`, ya que no devuelve nada) lo asignas a `foto.onload`.

Seguramente lo que intentas hacer es algo como:

```
function callbackGenerator(nr) {
  return function () {
    self.dataphoto[nr]["width"] = foto.width;
    self.dataphoto[nr]["height"] = foto.height;
  }
}

foto.onload=callbackGenerator(i);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda... justamente lo solucione con una solución parecida, voy a revisar ambas respuestas para entender bien lo que sucede...